# FragmentPagerAdapter Uses Wrong Page

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, tabs, android-actionbar

i try to use ActionBarTabs like Twitter's swipeable tabs in android. I have three tabs and three asynctasks every tab has gridview in each other. But my view use tabs randomly. For example when page open FragmentOne will be loaded in second view. When i go secondview FragmentTwo loads third view. When i go third one i see second one. When i back second one i see first views content. Where is my mistake do you think?

```
    pageType = getIntent().getIntExtra("type", 0);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });
    // Adding Tabs
    if (pageType != 3) {
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }
    } else {
        for (String tab_name : tabs_multi) {
            bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }
    }


public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        String text = getActionBar().getSelectedTab().getText().toString();
        if (text.equals("Futbol")) {
            return new FragmentOne(pageType);
        } else if (text.equals("Basketbol")) {
            return new FragmentTwo(pageType);
        } else if (text.equals("Voleybol")) {
            return new FragmentThree(pageType);
        } else if (text.equals("Video")) {
            return new FragmentOne(pageType);
        } else if (text.equals("Albüm")) {
            return new FragmentTwo(pageType);
        } else if (text.equals("Sesler")) {
            return new FragmentThree(pageType);
        } 

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you are supposed to implement a PagerAdapter.getItem function. Android will call this function for each possible index to get the fragment that should be shown on that tab. Since your getCount returns 3, your getItem function should have a switch statement with case statements for 0, 1, and 2, and you should construct one of your 3 fragments in each case statement. The PagerAdapter will then keep track of those fragment instances and return them.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new FragmentOne();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentTwo();
        case 2:
            return new FragmentThree();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm a bit confused about how the selected tab and the text are working, but you really do need to have just three fragments, with one on each tab.

Comment: This technique was my first try but it didnt work. When you say i try it again but it doesnt work